# Is it possible to dynamically create a resource name?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm writing to a CSV file and using `FlatFileItemWriter` to do it. I have a bean with that as my class, and I also have a property for the resource, where I provide the file name to use to write out the item.

Is it possible to append the date and time to the file name?

Right now I am telling it to write out to a file called report.csv, instead I want it to write out to a file called report-7-2-2014-16-03.csv

**Here's the XML Config for the writer**

```
<bean id="csvWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
            <constructor-arg value="${REPORT_FILENAME}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="com.example.CSVLineAggregator" />
    </property>
    <property name="headerCallback">
        <bean class="com.example.CSVHeaderWriter" >
            <constructor-arg value="${REPORT_HEADER}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to extend `FileSystemResource` and do the date creation there. But is there a cleaner and simpler way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462669/create-new-output-file-using-flatfileitemwriter-in-spring-batch?rq=1

Comment: to extend Lucas answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540618/62201, you can create the filename on the fly inside your job with e.g. a tasklet which puts the name into the jobExecution which can be used for late-binding as well

Answer (score 4):

You need to [configure your step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html) with late binding to solve your problem.
Late binding allow you to evaluate an expression during job/step execution and not in a static way (during xml pasring, to be clear) using values stored in jobParameters and job or step execution context; thise contexts are available only during job/step execution!
To enable this feature:

1. mark your artifacts with special `step="scope"`
2. Add to jobParameters with name 'REPORT_FILENAME' and value 'report-7-2-2014-16-03.csv' (of course this value will change every time you launch the job and is your reponsibility to make it unique and create with right date/time)
3. use spEL with special `#{jobParameters['REPORT_FILENAME']}` expression to let SB extract the report name from job parameters dinamically

---

```
<bean id="csvWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file://report-dir/#{jobParameters['REPORT_FILENAME']}" />
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="com.example.CSVLineAggregator" />
    </property>
    <property name="headerCallback">
        <bean class="com.example.CSVHeaderWriter" >
            <constructor-arg value="${REPORT_HEADER}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is just a small example but you can read more about [Late binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#Late-Binding)

Comment: Regarding step two, is there a way with spring to obtain the current date and time?